# Is it possible to build a complex query using expression tree

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I have this method that gives me a collection of filtred movies by actor

```
private IList<Movie> FilterByActor(IList<Actor> Actors)
{
    //from moviesToFilter from context
    return Actors != null ? moviesToFilter
        .Where(movie => Actors.All(requiredActor => 
            movie.MovieActor.Any(movieActor => movieActor.Actor == requiredActor)))
        .ToList() : null;
}
```

The problem is that expect of Actors I want to filter by Directors, Writers, Genres etc. And for each of these filter I need a similar method which make my code overweight.

So, it would be great to have one method that build an appropriate query.

I know that Expression trees are used for this meter and I built some simple query before. But this query is much more complex and I have no idea how to build it dynamically.

Any ideas or examples?

Comment: `Actors == null ? moviesToFilter.Where(movie => Actors.All...` I see a NullReferenceException right there

Comment: @Camilo, you right. Going to fix

Comment: Your where implies that every returned movie should have the entire `Actors` collection as part of its `MovieActor` collection. Is this wanted?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto, No. It's kind of complex filtration. I have many-to-many relationship. Movie-MovieActor-Actor. And by this method I want to get a collection of movies in which each of them has at list one actor from list that I pass to the method. Again, this code works, but it will have many similar methods. What I wan't is to avoid it by using `Expression Trees`.

Comment: Why not just `.Where(movie => Actors.Select(a => a.ActorId).Contains(movie.MovieActor.Select(ma => ma.ActorId))`?

Comment: In fact, I'd even pass `IEnumerable<int>` instead of that `IList<Actor>`

Comment: [PredicateBuilder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) might help as a library or example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have the main filtering be done by a method that takes a function that describes the collection to search (actors, directors etc.).

```
public IList<Movie> FilterByActor(ICollection<Actor> actors) {
    return FilterBy(m => m.MovieActor, actors);
}

public IList<Movie> FilterByDirector(ICollection<Director> directors) {
    return FilterBy(m => m.MovieDirectors, directors);
}

private IList<Movie> FilterBy<T>(Func<Movie, ICollection<T>> fn, ICollection<T> required) {
    return moviesToFilter.Where(m => fn(m).Any(a => required.Contains(a))).ToList();
}
```